# How to join tables in Django 1.8

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have tried to access joined data in my django template but nothing works, a little help is deeply appreciated.

```
Model1():
   project_code = Foreignkey(another table1)
   shot_code = charfield(primary_key = True)
   shot_name = charfield()
   sequence_name = Integerfield()

Model2():
   vendor_id = Foreignkey(another table2)
   shot_code = Foreignkey(Model1, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
   shot_rate = integerfield()
   shot_bid = integerfield()
```

I wanted to display

```
Select * from Model1 a, Model2 b, where a.shot_code = b.shot_code 
and model1.project_code = "XXX"
```

and columns to be accessed in template are

```
1. Shot code
2. Shot name
3. Sequence name
4. Shot rate
5. Shot bid
6. Vendor id
```

I tried the following method

```
1. Using Select_related
    result = only values of model2 is displayed
    unable to access model1's data, 
    error = 'QuerySet' object has no attribute model1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you expect this to return one or multiple instances? The best way to do this would be still with `select_related`, e.g.:

```
Model2.objects.filter(shot_code__project_code=<your value>).select_related("shot_code")
```

For queryset with multiple `Model2` instances, or add `.get()` at the end if you expect only single instance.

Alternatively, you can add `.values()` and instead of operating on two related models, get dict-like join result (although note that you won't be able to reuse `shot_code` straightforward, as it would clash with your foreign key name):

```
Model2.objects.filter(shot_code__project_code=<your value>).annotate(
    sequence_name=F("shot_code__sequence_name"),
    shot_name=F("shot_code__shot_name"),
    real_shot_code=F("shot_code__shot_code")
).values(
    "sequence_name", "shot_name", "real_shot_code", "shot_rate", "shot_bid", "vendor_id"
)
```

And as always, I recommend to refrain from naming your `ForeignKey` as `vendor_id`, since it will place the real id under the `vendor_id_id`, and naming will be a bit unclear.

Comment: OMG !
This thing helped,
Why does JOINS in Django has to be this complicated, 

I learnt what I did missed, Thanks for the solution, I missed using annotate and the values. 

I shall work on renaming the foreign key as you adviced, thanks

Comment: You can always skip annotate and use `.values()` with related names, e.g. "shot_code__shot_code", it just would't be that friendly to use later in the template ;)

Comment: Understood, but still out of curiosity, is there any simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Not one that I am aware of (but I still happen to discover some unknown django features), at least in terms of straightforward join result. The select related would work similarly, but then you need to access all values by the relations (e.g. `instance.shot_code.shot_code`), and there is of course an added overhead of creating the objects and retrieving all fields from db.

Comment: agreed, the overhead here is accessing individual columns with references/relations instead of direct join :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use object of Model1 query set in Model2 and get the data see below example:

```
model1obj = Model1.objects.get(project_code = "XXX")
model2obj = Model2.objects.get(shot_code = model1obj)

# now access all the fields using model1obj  and model2obj
```

Comment: this leads to 
1. Multiple hits on db
2. Confusion while accessing the data in template

Comment: In Djago querysets won't do multiple hits on db for more info check [querysets-are-lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy)